# Combining a C# and C++ project works for x86 and x64 but not for ARM

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I have two projects in my solution. One is a C# Universal Application and the other is a C++ project (obtained from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/03/06/developing-a-winrt-component-to-create-a-video-file-using-media-foundation.aspx)) and re-targetted to Windows 8.1 (this was performed by Visual Studio 15 when I imported the project). I have referenced the C++ project from my C# project and set Copy Local to true.

The code builds perfectly fine for all three platforms (x86, x64 and ARM). However, when deployed to an ARM device there is an exception thrown on the line where I try to access the C++ code. On the x86 and x64 versions this is not an issue and the code works perfectly fine. The exception is a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` and [here is a pastebin of the exception in detail](http://pastebin.com/1MXm29Uz).

My understanding of this exception is that the generated .dll is for some reason not being copied over onto the device? I have had a look at the configuration settings and everything seems set up correctly as far as I can tell (screenshot incuded below). The other possibility is that the C++ project has an internal dependency on another class that I somehow need to identify and reference from somewhere. There is a line from the stacktrace (included in the above pastebin link) that suggests it occurs on the line `System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetWinRTFactoryObject(IntPtr pCPCMD)`.

The C++ code uses Media Foundation WinRT components and should work perfectly fine on ARM devices.

It seems that other questions on SO (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734610/x86-dll-works-but-not-x64-dll)) have also looked at this but only for one particular platform such as x86.

Is there any particular reason why this currently works on x86 and x64 but not on ARM?

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @HansPassant I've been struggling with this for a while now. I'm obviously familiar with the debugger but how would I specifically check for MFStartup() failing? Could you give me some advice for things to try? I'm unsure.

Comment: The C++ DLL will need to link with the C runtime.  Are the correct versions of those DLLs installed on the ARM device?  I've had this error for that reason often enough over the years.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Which DLLs specifically? The C++ DLL is my own so I assume you mean the runtime? Both devices have the most recent versions of Windows 10 Insider Preview. How would I check which version of the runtime DLL the phone has?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the runtime.  I don't know how to check what's on the phone.  Is there something similar to Dependency Walker (Depends.exe) that you can run on the phone?

Comment: Maybe this will help [How to Resolve mscorlib Related Issues in Visual Studio/MSBuild](https://blog.lextudio.com/2013/08/how-to-resolve-mscorlib-related-issues-in-visual-studiomsbuild/)

Answer (score 3):

> and re-targetted to Windows 8.1

That's your problem right there. If you target a Windows 10 device, you need to create a new Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows):

[image: Universal Windows (10) C++ Windows Runtime Component]

My guess is that the Windows 8.1 Winmd is not compatible with the device you selected.

I have downloaded the VideoRecorder tool, and reproduced your problem. Then if I create a new Winmd Universal Windows, add the C++ files in it, it runs without issues on a Raspberry Pi 2 with Windows 10 IoT.

EDIT: If you are targeting a Windows 8.1 device and not a Windows 10 device then you need the Universal Windows 8.1 project:

[image: Universal Windows 8.1 C++ Windows Runtime Component]

I've made a sample and deployed it on a Nokia Lumia 925 without issues.

Comment: This looks good. I've implemented it but unfortunately it seems that I have a new problem (that is separate to this thread) involving an error message during deployment. [I've posted a question about it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247835/why-am-i-getting-a-package-could-not-be-registered-deployment-error-on-windows). Once I get this solved I can let you know if your solution here has worked or not and reward the bounty if it has.

Comment: What device are you targetting ? I deployed the sample on a Raspberry Pi 2 with Windows 10 IoT.

Comment: Interesting. I'm targetting a Nokia Lumia 820.

Comment: Ok I thought you were using the new Universal App for Windows 10, but if you are targeting a Windows 8.1 device, you need another project type. I have updated my answer after I tested with a Lumia 925. If you are still struggling I can provide you with the sample solutions I used.

Comment: I have Windows 10 installed on the Lumia 820. Will this still cause an issue?

Comment: I have Windows 10 installed on the Lumia 925 too :) I couldn't deploy the Windows 10 app on it because I didn't have the newest version, I'm downloading the update right now and I'll test again.